# Is memory type returned by makeedge() is of static or dynamic type?

Tags: c++

What type of memory allocation is this in `makedge` function?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct edge
{
    int a;
    int b;
    edge(int a, int b)
    {
        this->a=a;
        this->b=b;
    }
};

edge makedge(int a, int b)
{
    return edge(a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    edge e=makedge(5 , 6);
    printf("%d %d\n", e.a, e.b);
}
```

When I try to free the memory using `delete(&e)`. The error is

```
Error : double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fff6aee5d30 ***
```

in geeksforgeeks online compiler.

Comment: Why are you using `free`/`delete` when you never used `*alloc`/`new`?  It sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dynamic allocation in your program.

All your objects have *automatic storage duration*.

Consequently, `delete`ing or `free`ing them is very bad.

Hence the error message.

---

```
return edge(a, b);
```

Here you returned a *temporary*, an object without name … but it was not dynamically allocated.

It's not totally different from:

```
edge myObject(a, b);
return myObject;
```